# ActiveMQ - Could not get JDBC connection with SQL Server 2012

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2012, activemq-classic

I try to replace kahaDB by SQL Server 2012 in ActiveMQ.

After of to implement the persistence with "SQL Server 2012" (http://activemq.apache.org/sqlserver.html).

I'm find the next problem:

activemq.log (summary)

```
2015-12-17 17:10:44,454 | INFO  | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@75dda1ae: startup date [Thu Dec 17 17:10:44 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 17:10:45,916 | INFO  | PListStore:[C:\apache-activemq-5.13.0\bin\win64\..\..\data\localhost\tmp_storage] started | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 17:10:45,951 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: JDBCPersistenceAdapter(org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@1bae0625) | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 17:10:45,961 | WARN  | Could not get JDBC connection: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=activedb' | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter | WrapperSimpleAppMain
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=activedb'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2161)[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2033)[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.TransactionContext.getConnection(TransactionContext.java:59)[activemq-jdbc-store-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.loadAdapter(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:449)[activemq-jdbc-store-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.createAdapter(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:432)[activemq-jdbc-store-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.getAdapter(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:381)[activemq-jdbc-store-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.init(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:296)[activemq-jdbc-store-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.LockableServiceSupport.preStart(LockableServiceSupport.java:89)[activemq-broker-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:54)[activemq-client-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.doStartPersistenceAdapter(BrokerService.java:664)[activemq-broker-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startPersistenceAdapter(BrokerService.java:653)[activemq-broker-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:617)[activemq-broker-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:73)[activemq-spring-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
2015-12-17 17:10:46,042 | INFO  | No IOExceptionHandler registered, ignoring IO exception | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
java.io.IOException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=activedb'
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:45)[activemq-client-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.TransactionContext.getConnection(TransactionContext.java:71)[activemq-jdbc-store-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.loadAdapter(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:449)[activemq-jdbc-store-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.createAdapter(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:432)[activemq-jdbc-store-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.getAdapter(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:381)[activemq-jdbc-store-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.init(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:296)[activemq-jdbc-store-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.LockableServiceSupport.preStart(LockableServiceSupport.java:89)[activemq-broker-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:54)[activemq-client-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.doStartPersistenceAdapter(BrokerService.java:664)[activemq-broker-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startPersistenceAdapter(BrokerService.java:653)[activemq-broker-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:617)[activemq-broker-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:73)[activemq-spring-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
2015-12-17 17:10:46,047 | ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([localhost, null], java.io.IOException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=activedb') | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 17:10:46,052 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.0 (localhost, null) is shutting down | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 17:10:46,054 | INFO  | Connector openwire stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 17:10:46,056 | INFO  | Connector amqp stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 17:10:46,058 | INFO  | Connector stomp stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 17:10:46,060 | INFO  | Connector mqtt stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 17:10:46,062 | INFO  | Connector ws stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 17:10:46,068 | INFO  | PListStore:[C:\apache-activemq-5.13.0\bin\win64\..\..\data\localhost\tmp_storage] stopped | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 17:10:46,077 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.0 (localhost, null) uptime 0.151 seconds | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 17:10:46,080 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.0 (localhost, null) is shutdown | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 17:10:46,082 | INFO  | Closing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@75dda1ae: startup date [Thu Dec 17 17:10:44 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 17:10:46,087 | WARN  | Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | WrapperSimpleAppMain
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@75dda1ae: startup date [Thu Dec 17 17:10:44 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:357)[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:881)[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:840)[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook.run(SpringContextHook.java:30)[activemq-spring-5.13.0.jar:5.13.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_66]
2015-12-17 17:10:46,151 | WARN  | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | WrapperSimpleAppMain
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=activedb'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
```

activemq.xml

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->

        <persistenceAdapter>
            <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="#mssql-ds" createTablesOnStartup="false"   />
        </persistenceAdapter>

          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="10 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="5 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!--SQL Server 2012 DataSource Setup -->
    <bean id="mssql-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=activedb"/>
        <property name="username" value="user"/>
        <property name="password" value="pass"/>
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Could you please help me fixing this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have the MSSQL driver jar file in your classpath ?

Comment: I tryed with the next driver (Sql Server 2012):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11774

I've put the drivers in the classpath: "home_apache/lib/" and "home_apache/lib/optional".

But doesn't work succesfully.

Could you provide me the correct drivers of Sql Server 2012.

Thanks for your collaboration,

Comment: IF you still have that problem: Could you show your directory setup including the sqljdbc.jar and where you put it?